# MySQL - WHERE IN (@blob) return only first row

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm updating a bunch of record and returning their ID, then i need to `SELECT` them.
Using `WHERE IN` i only get the first row.
How can i `SELECT` all of them?

```
SET @updated := null;
UPDATE table1 set table1.enabled = 0 WHERE table1.limit > 10 AND (SELECT @updated := CONCAT_WS(', ', table1.id, @updated));
SELECT * from table1 where table1.id IN (@updated);
```

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: @cybermonkey Well, i need to select all of them, not just the first one.

Comment: Use a 'SELECT * from `table`', then iterate through the table items.

Comment: Why not something like `SET @updated := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ,) FROM table1 WHERE limit > 10);` first?

Comment: i ended up selecting first and then updating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put it in the `where` clause. You can do it like this:

```
SET @updated := null;
UPDATE table1 
set table1.enabled = 0 
, id = if(@updated := concat_ws(', ', table1.id, @updated), id, id)
WHERE table1.limit > 10; 
SELECT * from table1 where table1.id IN (@updated);
```

Don't worry, your id will not be touched, MySQL doesn't update a column, if the value doesn't change.

Note though, that you could as well select first and update later.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') INTO @updated FROM table1 WHERE limit > 10;
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

Do this in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks, second solution may be more adapted!